# Two Routers on the Same Subnet

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, subnet, powerline-networking

So I've been fiddling with an issue all afternoon, and think it's time to reach out.

I live in a house with concrete walls, so I decided to buy a second router and some Ethernet-over-powerline adapters so I could extend my network upstairs. I have the EoP adapter plugged into a LAN port on my downstairs router (Router A) and the other end feeds into Router B's WAN port.

I can connect to the internet just fine, but I can seem to get devices on Router B's network to see any of the devices on Router A. Specifically, I have a USB drive hooked into the USB port of Router A I'd like to be able to see from upstairs.

Both routers are TP-Link AX6000's. There's a tab under "Operation Mode" that turns Router B into an "Access Point." So far, if I select that, I can get into the router's initial settings after a reboot, but once the settings are saved, the router becomes unconnectable and I can't get back into the settings. I tried the manual way of assigning router B a static IP on router A, connecting LAN port to LAN port and disabling the DHCP server on router B. No dice, pretty similar results. Even after the manual way of doing it, I still lose connection to Router B and can't connect anything.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm wondering if the EoP adapters are to blame, but it's weird that everything works just fine with my initial setup.

Comment: Are you unable to connect to the router's Wi-Fi signal, or to its management webpage?

Comment: you should be able to access the 'access' point using the AP's IP (which you can find from the other router). My mercusys (which are a 'lower end' rebrand of TPlink) also have a generic domain name for accessing the admin page that works if you're connected to the right AP. It might be helpful to add screenshots of your router setup pages

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way you connected it, it does exactly what it is designed to do.

A router creates a new network for all the LAN ports and shields that from the WAN port. Otherwise connecting a router would expose your LAN to the internet, and that's not what you want.

It would've been better if you bought a switch rather than a router, but not all hope is lost. If you disable the DHCP server from the router and plug the PoE cable into one of the LAN ports on the 2nd router, rather than its WAN port, you effectively turn that router into a switch and wireless Access Point.

The problem is that you can't use the WAN port.